# Всплывающая подсказка перекрывается панелью навигации

Tags: дефект

Если зайти в профиль любого пользователя и открыть вкладку `Активность` - справа можно увидеть блок `Влияние` и надпись `~Х людей затронул`. Tooltip к этой надписи перекрывается верхней панелью навигации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]